# Working with Bluetooth in android kernel development linux

Tags: c++, android, c, bluetooth, kernel

I want to know how can I work with Bluetooth in android using **C/C++** not **JAVA API** if somebody have useful links or can give advice ?

I found **[this](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/bluetooth.html)** post but I want to know if i gives complete information ?

Comment: Did you find the library that you can use it on both android and iOS  for BLE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During my research I found this, and now I want somebody tell me what is **hciattach**, **hcid** and where to know how can I work in **Userspace**

[image]

- bluez: it provides 'hcid' daemon and it's responsible for all related bluetooth services
  dbus-daemon: the bridge between hcid and system server
- D-Bus is a simple inter-process communication (IPC) system for software applications to communicate with one another.
- debug utility: d-feet (a dbus UI debugger ), dbus-monitor (debug probe to print message bus messages), dbus-send (Send a message to a message bus)
- bluez dbus API document: /mydroid/external/bluez/utils/hcid/dbus-api.txt
- one example as below

Here is [**article**](http://i-miss-erin.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-bluetooth-introduction-part-i.html) that gives all answers !